# Listings: overloaded use of dash

Tags: listings, highlighting

In my language, I use the dash character `-` in three different contexts.

1. As an operator, e.g., `5 - 1`.
2. As a minus sign, e.g., `-10`.
3. As part of a keyword, e.g., `some-keyword`.

I would like to have a different style for each of these. Is this possible?

**What I tried so far.** Let me start from the most naive minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyLang}{
keywords={},
otherkeywords={+,-}, % operators
morekeywords=[2]{akeyword, other-keyword}, % keywords
}

\lstset{
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta}, % operators
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{violet}}, % keywords
  language=MyLang
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
5 - 1 + -10   akeyword   some-keyword
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

This results in all dashes being styled as an operator. However, I would like the second dash to be rendered black, and the third one purple. Note that the keyword containing a dash is not recognized at all.

[image: naive]

For the minus sign, I found a workaround using the `literate` option of `listings`. For example, by adding `literate={_}{\textminus}1,` to the language definition, I can rewrite the example program as `5 - 1 + _10   akeyword   some-keyword` which results in the following.

[image: workaround]

Of course, this is not ideal, because I have to replace each minus sign with an underscore manually, but in my case I find this acceptable. Still, bonus points if there is a solution for this. :)

For the keyword, I understood from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179923/149123) that adding `alsoletter=-,` should do the trick, but this does not seem to work.

Comment: Your `some-keyword` isn't highlighted even if you use `alsoletter=-` because your language setup uses `other-keyword` (which isn't the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `alsoletter={-}` the `-` is considered a letter. This way things like `-1` (or any number) become an unknown keyword, so aren't highlighted as a single keyword. Also, this way it can be used in the middle of another keyword you want to define with `morekeywords`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{MyLang}{
alsoletter={-},
keywords={-}, % operators
otherkeywords={+},
keywords=[2]{akeyword,some-keyword}, % keywords
}

\lstset{
  keywordstyle=[1]\color{magenta}, % operators
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{violet}}, % keywords
  language=MyLang
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
5 - 1 + -10   akeyword   some-keyword
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

*Caveat*: In `5-1` the `-` will not be highlighted as a binary operator (you need spaces).

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow, and now that I added this answer I read the last part of your question and see you already considered `alsoletter`... Well, here is how you should use it!